# Hibernate jpa remove child from table when it removed from parent collection and update parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

i have a relation (one to many/ many to one) between parent and child in my code like this

The Parent

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent{

    private Integer id;
    private List<Child> childs;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="idparent")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection (LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }
    public void setChilds(List<Child> childs) {
        for (Child child: childs) {
            child.setParent(this);
        }
        this.childs= childs;
    }
}
```

and the child

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child{

    private Integer id;
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "idchild")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idparent")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent= parent;
    }
}
```

Everything is ok but when i do somthink like

```
parent.getChilds().remove(child);
session.update(parent);
```

the child is'nt removed from the table, what is the problem, can you help me please,
sorry for my bad english :-(

Comment: You already have an accepted answer, given by one of the main developers of the Hibernate project ... so why do you reopen this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`child` should not be removed from the database in this case.  If that is the behavior you want, you need to enable "orphan removal":

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@LazyCollection (LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<Child> getChilds() {
    return childs;
}
```

Comment: I think that this solution is used to remove all childs when remove parent, but what i want is to remove child that removed from prent collection from the child table; when i update parent.

Comment: same problem here, solution does not work. I only want to delete a child. The parent and all other child shall keep existing. 'remove(child)' does not remove the child from DB. At onToMany of parentes cascadeAll is defined in case parent is deleted to delete all its childs. Works fine but isnt the question here.

Answer (score 0):

It May be helpful

```
Child c = (Child) parent.getChilds();
parent.getChilds().remove(c);
c.setParent(null);
```

or

```
Child c = (Child) parent.getChilds();
parent.getChilds().remove(c);
session.delete(c);
```

Comment: to remove child from the parents list is not the same as calling entityManager.remove(). So ur suggestion may only works together with orphanRemoval?.